# How to set default model type in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor View

Tags: asp.net, razor, view, types, model

i've been looking to this for some time and i couldn't find an answer so, here we go:
All the views in my app will be strongly typed and have the same model type.
I know i could just add: `@model ModelType` in the beginning of all the views, but, there is a way to set the default view type for all my views?

I know i can replace `@using` tags by `<namespace>` tags in the Views/Web.Config file.